# jQuery Orientation Change not Working

Tags: jquery, orientation, screen-orientation, device-orientation

here is my code:

```
jQuery(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
   var maxHeight = -1;
   jQuery('.article .articleHead').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > jQuery(this).height() ? maxHeight : jQuery(this).height();
   });
   jQuery('.article .articleHead').each(function() {
     jQuery(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
   alert("The orientation has changed!");
});
```

What I am trying to do is simply run that code when the orientation is changed. The code inside is just getting the tallest specified element and then setting all other elements to match that height with inline styling.

But this is not working. All I get is the alert message. Nothing adjusts.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

});
```

The above works just fine. When the page loads it sets all the inline height styling accordingly.

I know I am missing something or trying to use this in a wrong way. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Agon

Comment: Really! No one has an answer to this. No one has even told me that im doing it wrong. So I have everything correct? So this means that I have found an error with the jQuery script then? Since no one seems to be able to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Probably your DOM is not ready when the orientation change event fires.

Add a delay in order to the whole DOM is available to jQuery:

```
jQuery(window).on("orientationchange",function(){
  setTimeout(function () {

   var maxHeight = -1;
   jQuery('.article .articleHead').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > jQuery(this).height() ? maxHeight : jQuery(this).height();
   });
   jQuery('.article .articleHead').each(function() {
     jQuery(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
   alert("The orientation has changed!");
    }, 200);

});
```

You can experiment other values than 200.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but that didn't work. It still doesn't change anything but does delay the alert message.

Comment: Please, try with a higher value, like 1000 for the timeout.